# Benders decomposition Master Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am currently working on implementation of Bender's Decomposition for MIP. I am looking at the simplest model
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min_{x,y} &\; c^Tx + f(y)\\
s.t. & \; Ax + Dy \ge b\\
& \; x\ge0, y\in\mathbb{Y}
\end{split}
\label{OP}
\end{equation}
Then the primal problem is formulated simply fixing complicating variable $y$.
The dual of it will be 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \max_{u} & \; \left(b - D\hat{y}\right)^T u \\
 s.t. &\; A^Tu\leq c \\
 & \; u\geq 0
\end{split}
\label{DSP}
\end{equation} 
Where $u$ is dual variable. Then the algorithm tells that Master problem is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min & \; f(y) + z \\
s.t. & \; z\geq \left(b - Dy\right)^T \hat{u}_j \quad \quad j=1,2,...,Q \\
& \; y\in\mathbb{Y}, z\in\mathbb{R}
\end{split}
\label{MP}
\end{equation}
Now assume that $y$ is binary vector variable. Algorithm tells me that dual primal problem is LP and I totally agree with that. Also it tells me that Master Problem is purely IP(Integer programming). And I don't understand why, because Master problem also includes variable $z$. My question: Why Master problem is purely IP and how do I get $z$? or if $z$ is a variable, how do I solve Master Problem?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few weeks of research I think I know the answer. $z$ is indeed unrestricted variable. But it is totally defined binary variable $y$. Hence the only variable need to be found is $y$. That is, the problem is purely IP.